# How to implement an SQLite Update command properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I am looking to use an update command to change all my users details, depending on the users email address. I have been told to use an update command, but I don't properly understand how to use one, and the online documentation is pretty poor. Can anyone help me out? 
Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static int database_version = 1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS + " TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT + " INTEGER," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL + " INTEGER );";


    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Table Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email, int weight, int goal) {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT, weight);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL, goal);
        long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "One Row Inserted");
        SQ.close();
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop) {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT, TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL};
        Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `database.exeSQL("update....");`

get all the data you want to change/update by a edit Text or something similar.

select an ID or name for the specific row you want to update in this example nombre is a name:

```
String[] args = new String[]{nombre};//name or id whatever you want
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + YOUR_TABLE + " SET columnName1='" + data1 + "', columnName2='"+data2+"' WHERE nombre_column=?", args); //using SET you say that the column will be update with a new string
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ALERT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the `update()` method, you will need to create a `ContentValues` Object with the values you wish to update, and use the email in the String array that you pass in to [whereArgs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

```
public void updateInformation(String name, String pass, String email, int weight, int goal) {
   SQLiteDatabase SQ = this.getWritableDatabase();

   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
   cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
   cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT,weight);
   cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL,goal);

   String[] args = new String[]{email};
   SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, cv, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL+" = ?", args);

   SQ.close();
}
```

One other thing I noticed in all your methods is that you pass in a `DatabaseOperations` reference, since this class already extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Instead of passing in `dop` in each method, just use `this`.

So in each method, instead of using `dop` as you do here:

```
SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
```

You can just reference `this`:

```
SQLiteDatabase SQ = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: how does the USER_EMAIL+" =?" work?? where do I input the email that I want it to match?

Comment: @JamesWolfe You just pass it into the method through the parameter, just as you do in your `putInformation` method.  The only difference here is that you need to put it into a String array with one entry.  Take a look at this line:  `String[] args = new String[]{email};`

Comment: @JamesWolfe Let me know if this code worked for you, or if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

**In your DB class**:

```
public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowOne, double rowTwo, double rowThree, String rowFour )
{
    // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowOne);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowTwo);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_THREE, rowThree);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_FOUR, rowFour);

    // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
    try {
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);}
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**To make an update:**

```
//Get an instance of the DB
//db.getInstance();
db.updateRow(rowID, rowOne, rowTwo, rowThree, rowFour);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have a content provider pattern, but this is how my update functions looks normaly

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    final SQLiteDatabase database = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();

    int rowsUpdated = 0;

    switch (match) {
        case USER:
            rowsUpdated = database.update(Database.Tables.USER,
                    values,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;

        case CONTACTLIST:
            rowsUpdated = database.update(Database.Tables.CONTACTLIST,
                    values,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs);
            break;
....

    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```